# Can Bursting the Cognos 8 Report Studio Report reduce the server load instead running them manually 200 times a day?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-10

My Cognos 8 Server is already slow as it is handling a number of Jobs which is used to Burst thousands of Report Studio Reports a day. Moreover, In the same server users are manually generating a particular report around 200 times a day.

My Question is if I modify that particular report to burst to those 200 users everyday, will that reduce or increase my server load ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely you will reduce the load.

if you burst a report it will be queried only once with a large dataset and then sliced into 200 reports, so you will reduce the load on the database (one query instead of 200 filtered ones). the cognos server will also have less load as it will only be processing one job.

however, if memory is an issue here (and how you have configured the virtual memory available to each cognosBIBus process), you may run into trouble when handling the large dataset that is to be sliced into 200 small ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you run those burst jobs outside business hours, you'll effectively distribute the load so that users don't see it.

If your users are running the same report with the same prompt selection, you can generate a saved output of the report run (storing report output as a file in content store) so it will be retrieved from content store when they access it instead of re-running it each time.

Cheers